# Karma: how to change preprocessors on commandline (or switch preprocessors in config)

Tags: javascript, command-line, karma-runner

I want to run Karma a couple of times with different preprocessors. Based on the failures, the karma exec listens to `--preprocessors` on the commandline, but I can't get it set up properly.

The following all return the same error.

```
karma start --single-run web-app/karma.conf.js --preprocessors "{\"../grails-app/assets/javascripts/**/!(lib)/**/*.js\": \"jshints\"}"
karma start --single-run web-app/karma.conf.js --preprocessors {"../grails-app/assets/javascripts/**/!(lib)/**/*.js": "jshints"}
karma start --single-run web-app/karma.conf.js --preprocessors "{'../grails-app/assets/javascripts/**/!(lib)/**/*.js': 'jshints'}"
```

The error:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:145
  Object.keys(preprocessors).forEach(function(pattern) {
         ^
TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
    at Function.keys (native)
    at normalizeConfig (/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:145:10)
    at Object.parseConfig (/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:293:10)
    at Object.exports.start (/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:282:20)
```

**Why am I doing this, are there any alternatives?**

The `coverage` and `jshint` preprocessors aren't compatible. I could copy the `karma.conf.js` but that's not a great long-term option for maintainability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `karma.conf.js` template.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
}
```

Create a wrapper for karma (let's call it 'wrapper.js'):

```
var karma = require('karma');

function configurator(options){
  var config = getTemplate();

  // based on the options object will add different preprocessors
  if(options.blah){
    config.preprocessors["../grails-app/assets/javascripts/**/!(lib)/**/*.js"] = 'whatever';
  }
  return config;
}

function getTemplate(){
    return {
      // start with an empty object
      preprocessors: {},
      // point to the template, we will enrich it
      configFile : __dirname + 'path/to/your/karma.conf.js'
    };
}

function startKarma(options){
  var config = configurator(options);
  karma.server.start(config, function(exitCode){
    // exit code === 0 is OK
    if (!exitCode) {
        console.log('\tTests ran successfully.\n');
        // rerun with a different preprocessor
        startKarma({blah1: true});
    } else {
        // just exit with the error code
        process.exit(exitCode);
    }
  });
}

function passedArg(string){
  // look at the arguments passed in the CLI
  return process.argv.indexOf(string) > -1;
}

function start(){
  // start with empty options
  var options = {};

  if(passedArg('blah')){
    options.blah = true;
  }
  //start karma!
  startKarma(options); 
}

start();
```

At this point you can pass the parameter from the console:

```
$ node wrapper.js blah
```

For more information about the karma API have a look at: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/dev/public-api.html